# How to set true the field isTracked in EmailMessage object

Tags: apex, email, email-tracking

I want to know how we can set to true the field isTracked in the object EmailMessage.

When I query this object some records has the field set to true and others set to false. I want to know if this field control if a EmailMessage is being tracked or just activating the Activity setting for Email Tracking I am fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This field is based on whether the email tracking is enabled or not.

Ref : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_enable_email_tracking.htm&type=5

The reason why this field is set to false for some emails and true to some emails because EmailMessage gets created for all the emails inbound and outbound. But salesforce only adds the tracking for the emails which were sent from salesforce. For all the inbound emails it would be false. This is documented in above documentation.